# Counting the distinct records from a view

Tags: mysql, sql

I think I know how to count distinct records from a table:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT device_guid) 
FROM 002_device_guid_group_and_device_data;
```

But 002_device_guid_group_and_device_data is a view not a table and is returning:

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'nimevents.002_device_guid_group_and_device_data' doesn't exist
```

Is there different syntax for running against a  view?

**Following Comments**

The view must exists:

```
DESCRIBE 002_guid_group_and_device_data;
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| device_guid     | char(37)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| etl_create_date | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| dwell_minutes   | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| device_brand    | varchar(128) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| device_product  | varchar(128) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| device_os       | varchar(128) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Looks like the view doesn't exist. Names starting with a digit are illegal in SQL, you might need to quote it `"002_device_guid_group_and_device_data"` not sure if MySQL accepts that even without the quotes

Comment: create view device_guid__count as select count(DISTINCT device_guid) cnt from Tablename;

Comment: which version are you using? there used to be a bug in mysql regarding the count on views. more info here: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=26209

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name names starting with a digit are not illegal - but I agree that they should be!

Comment: @Strawberry: they are according to the SQL standard

Comment: My guess is that the view was created in a different database.